# Property Change not being updated in the View dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inotifypropertychanged

My binding is not updating the View in real-time when an OnPropertyChanged is called. I am able to set breakpoints to see the value being changed in the View Model. The View eventually updates when I make another selection, but not in real-time. I believe I know what the problem is, but I am struggling with fixing the problem. I think the problem is that I am calling the CreateChartNode method that is creating a new instance.

In my View Model, it looks like this:

```
public class ChartObjectVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
public ChartNode
{
   get
 {
   return CreateChartNode();
 }
}

private string fullText;
public string FullText
{
 get
 {
   return this.fullText;
 }
 set
 {
   this.fullText = value;
   OnPropertyChanged("FullText");
 }








public ChartNode CreateChartNode()
{
 ChartNode newChartNode = new ChartNode();
```

And in my ViewModel I am doing:

```
public void CreateNode()
{
  ChartObjectVM cObjectVM = new ChartObjectVM();
  ChartNode = cObjectVM.CreateNode();
 }
```

My binding in the View looks like:

```
{Binding Path = SelectedChartObject.UserObject.FullText, UpdatedSourceTrigger=PropertyChange, Mode=TwoWay}
```

Where SelectedChartObject is the currently selected ChartObjectVM.

Like I have said, I am pretty sure the problem is the CreateNode() method being called. I think there are two instances under the hood but I can't figure out why.

Comment: Is FullText property part of ChartObjectVM or ChartNode?                    Is the INotifyPropertyChanged implemented by both?

Comment: It is used in ChartObjectVM.

Comment: Then shouldn't your binding be SelectedChartObject.FullText?

Comment: UserObject is a property of ChartNode. ChartNodeObject contains a ChartNode property

Comment: You should post your entire code because what you are saying doesn't make any sense

Comment: ChartNode is its own separate class. Within my ChartObjectVM I have a property of type ChartNode. In ChartObject I have a property called FullText. ChartNodes have a property inside them called Text which I want to set to ChartObjectVM’s FullText property and update it OnPropertyChange.